# How to write Regex to remove parts in beginning of string and end of string, and save parts in the middle

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this;

`myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (Administrator)"`

How do I remove all parts except the `MyUserName`?

So far I've only managed to remove the `(Administrator)` part.

```
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", ""));
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: As I wrote, I just want the `MyUserName` part.

Comment: What about: `myString.replace("Logged in as: ", "")` as you can already remove the user role.

Comment: Well, that doesn't remove the `(Administrator)` part. I could do this in steps, but thought there had to be one regex that could deal with everything in one operation?

Comment: @chrkad ...you could combine both. Spend some effort ;-)

Comment: @chrkad If input string pattern is same why not use indexof(":") and indefOf("(") . to get substring between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final String myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (Administrator)";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^:]++:\\s*+(\\S++).*+$");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output

```
MyUserName
```

This uses possesive matchers which are [faster when no match is found](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html).

Comment: +1 for the anchors (`^` and `$`), too.  I know they're not really needed when you use the `matches()` method, but it makes the regex more self-documenting, and it helps prevent confusion if you switch to a solution based on `find()` or `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use matching group. You can use "(" and ")" to match a part of you regex and then replace all string with the content of the group.

Here is an example:

```
String myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (Administrator)";
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("^[^:]*:\\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\\s.*$", "$1"));
```

Outputs:

```
MyUserName
```

The regex

```
^[^:]*:\\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\\s.*$
```

contains matching group ([a-zA-Z]+), that matches the user name. The some entire string get replaced with the content of this first matched group (in this case $1).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the string always starts with `Logged in as:`, then you can try this:

```
    String myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (with parentheses) (Administrator)";
    String login = myString.substring("Logged in as:".length(), myString.lastIndexOf('(')).trim();
```

which returns `MyUserName (with parentheses)`

You can replace `lastIndexOf` with `indexOf` if you are sure that your user name cannot contain parentheses.

A simpler version would then be:

```
    String myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (with parentheses) (Administrator)";
    String login = myString.substring(myString.indexOf(':'), myString.indexOf('(')).trim();
```

Comment: I would prefer a regex solution for this particular example. It's compact, more flexible and better maintainable.

Comment: But less readable, and certainly longer to execute. For the maintainability part, I'm not sure that a regexp will improve things if the string you are analyzing has such a simple format. But you have the final decision ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this regex with your input:

```
[^:]*:\s*([^(]*).*
```

or in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^:]*:\\s*([^(]*).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Logged in as: MyUserName (Administrator)");
if(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

By the way, [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) is your friend to write regexes :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: `myString.replaceAll(".+:(.+)\\(.+\\)", "$1")`

It will match all the characters up to and including the first `:`. Once it finds that, it writes all the next characters into a capture group until it finds the first `(`. It will then replace all the matched content (which should be the entire string) with the content of the capture group, which is the `MyUserName` section.

Another version could be this: `myString.replaceAll(".+:\\s*(.+)\\s*\\(.+\\)", "$1")` which would remove any extra white space characters from the `MyUserName` section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll(".*?:\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1");
```

This ignores everything up to the first colon, the colon itself and  any whitespace following it, captures the username and ignores everything following it. It then replaces the entire match (i.e. the entire String) with the first captured group, i.e. the username.

See also the pattern syntax docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
String myString = "Logged in as: MyUserName (Administrator)";
String myUserName = myString.replaceAll(".+:(.+)(\\(.+)", "$1").trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should use Pattern object, with a matcher you can extract your parameters. This code can help you :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Logged in as: (.)+ (Administrator)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
   return m.group(1);
}

else {
   System.out.println("Not found !");
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I think you mean `(.+)`.  `(.)+` captures one character at a time, each time overwriting the previous character, so `group(1)` ends up containing just `e`, not `MyUserName`.  More generally, I don't think you can assume the rest of the string will always be literally `"Logged in as: "` and `" (Administrator)"`.  That is, making it case insensitive probably isn't good enough.